# How to remember show and hide div with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I have HTML like :

```
<div id='mainleft-content'>content is visible</div>
<div id="expand-hidden">Button Expand +</div>
```

And I use Jquery to show/hide div like :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#expand-hidden").click(function () {
        $("#mainleft-content").toggle();
    });
});
```

I want use cookie to remember the state of div is hide or show of visitors' manipulate.

How can I do it? Thank for your help.

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b8LrB/)

Comment: Thank for all suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/b8LrB/3/)

You may use `is(":visible")` for this purpose, it will return you whether div is visible or not:

```
if ( $("#mainleft-content").is(":visible") ){
   alert('its visible');
}
else{
   alert('div is hidden');
}
```

if you still need the cookies, you may add a function:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

and set the cookie:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#expand-hidden").click(function () {
        $("#mainleft-content").toggle();
        SetCookie("DivStateVisible", $("#mainleft-content").is(":visible"),5);
    });
});
```

with **jQuery** using [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    $.cookie(c_name, value, { expires : exdays });
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    return $.cookie(c_name);
}
```

Comment: you have not mention to my question yet. what about cookie?

Comment: Can you give me update on my demo? I tested but it cannot save state. what wrong with me? :(

Comment: @happi check fiddle now

Answer (score 2):

Using http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mainleft-content").toggle(!!$.cookie("visible"));
    $("#expand-hidden").click(function () {
        $("#mainleft-content").toggle(function() { 
             $.cookie("visible", $("#mainleft-content").is(':visible') ? 1 : 0);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

and just set states like

```
$.cookie("visible", 1);
```