# jQuery to remove div & set cookie to never show again

Tags: jquery, html, function, cookies, click

I am using the following html / jQuery to remove a div after clicking a link.

When clicking the link, I also need to set a cookie that keeps the div as 'removed' when the same visitor comes back to the site.

**HTML**

```
<div id="close-me">
    bye bye - being removed on click of close link
</div>

<p>
  <a href="#" class="close-div">Close</a>
</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  jQuery(".close-div").click(function(){
    jQuery("#close-me").remove();
  });
});
```

I would assume ***jquery.cookie.js*** is the best solution.

How would I do this?

[JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/phil_joostrap/c9q8nktc/)

Comment: This previous answer might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/a/20770311/6261948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Cookie is **no longer maintened**, so I would not go for it. Instead, you can use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) which is recommended as replacement by the dev team of jQuery Cookie.

Once loaded, it will be :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if (typeof Cookies.get('hide-div') !== 'undefinied') {
        $("#close-me").remove();
    }

    $(".close-button").click(function() {
        $("#close-me").remove();
        Cookies.set('hide-div', true);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.2/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="close-me">
  <i class="close-button">&times;</i>
  Your content here
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to edit the jQuery so it captures the root of the domain and remove the same div from all pages?
At the moment it is removing from only /about-us or /contact-us -- when you click to another page, the div with the same ID is still there.

Comment: jQuery just work on the page where it execute. So you can "run it to your root host". But if you include the script on all your pages or in the header/footer of your site which is on all your page, will work ;)

Comment: There is a spelling mistake in the code. It is written as " undefinied', it should be "undefined"

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this (without plugin):

```
var setCookie = function(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

var getCookie = function(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
  return "";
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  console.log(getCookie("closed"));
  if (getCookie("closed") == "closed") {
    $("#close-me").hide();
  }

  jQuery(".close-div").click(function() {
    jQuery("#close-me").remove();
    setCookie("closed", "closed", 365)
  });
});
```

Your fiddle updated : https://jsfiddle.net/nn42z27t/

This example comes from : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed use the jQuery cookie library here. Once on load to check if the cookie is set and remove the div, and once when clicking the remove link to set the cookie, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($.cookie('hide-div')) {
        $("#close-me").remove();
    }

    $(".close-div").click(function() {
        $("#close-me").remove();
        $.cookie('hide-div', true);
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c9q8nktc/1/)

Don't forget to include the jQuery cookie library in your page. I used a copy from [this CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-cookie).

Comment: The only issue I have is that it removes the div from view/the browser - but when I view the source I still see the div... I need to completely remove the div & everything contained inside of it.
I am trying to remove the whole div completely and all on the contained images from loading next time.

Comment: It's not possible to remove something from the source on the client side. jQuery's `remove()` method only removes the element from the DOM. If you need that behaviour you would need to check the cookie on the server and change the HTML before it is sent to the browser.

Comment: Is there an easy way to check the users cookie server side and change the HTML before it is sent to the browser?

Comment: Yes, but how you do it depends on what server-side language you're using. You would be best to start a new question for that.